# How to save data in models with oneToOne relationship

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.7

I have this model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

If I receive the data `username`, `firstname`, `lastmame`, `email,passsword`, `role`, How am I going to create a profile for this user, given that 'role' is not in the `User model`. its in `UserProfile model`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very basic but it works and I'm guessing you're using the Django `User` model?

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
user.first_name = firstname
user.last_name = lastname
user.save()

user_profile, created = UserProfile.objects.create_or_create(user=user, role=role)
```

What I would recommend doing if you find yourself doing this a lot is overriding the manager `objects` with a custom manager method.

```
class UserProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def create_profile(self, user, role):
        profile = self.create(user=user, role=role)
        return profile
```

you could then call it with this:

```
profile = UserProfile.objects.create_profile(user, role)
```